How do you set a Dim and Set a ContentControl box?
I have a Word doc that has Content Control boxes and Form Fields.
My macro deals with the Form Fields without issue because of:
Dim oMPERFields As FormFields
Set oMPERFields = LogFile.Formfields

The FormField content gets sent to another doc where the data sits in a new report.
But when I try and do the same for the Content Control boxes:
Dim oLogFields As ContentControl
Set oLogFields = LogFile.ContentControl

I get a Object doesn't support this type of method error.
Exactly as above, but so far no result.
The line for moving the CC data to the CC data in the other form is:
oLogFields ("Test").Result = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlByTitle("Test2")(1).Range.Text

If LogFile is an instance of type Document, the correct collection is ContentControls (plural).
You can check the names of functions, collections and properties when you open the object catalog in the window "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications" where you also edit source code. Press hotkey F2 to open that window, it is also available via the toolbar or the "View" menu.
Inside the object catalog you can use the search function and get infos for parameters in functions etc.

Thanks, I will take a look, I did try the plural I think but I will try it again!

I put the plural in and it now states 'Type Mismatch'

did you adjust the Dim to the type with ContentControls (plural) too?

Yes, I sorted the issue, the reference was pointing to the wrong document! By using Debug.Print I was able to spot which doc was active and which one needed to be referenced but thank you for the follow up.
